# Using sshfs to mount a remote filesystem on OSX fails periodically with "Bad address"

Tags: macos, filesystems, mount, osx-el-capitan, sshfs

I have a remote filesystem which I mount on my Mac (10.11) with the following command:

```
sudo sshfs username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ ~/mnt/remotefs
```

Sometimes this command works just fine, and it prompts me for a password and the filesystem is mounted. But other times, it just fails with a cryptic `Bad address` error. I'm not sure what's causing the failures - there's apparently no verbose option for `sshfs`, so I'm not sure how else I can figure out what's going on. ssh-ing in always works though, so it's not an availability issue.

Comment: What is the whole error you can see?

Comment: @Jakuje - that's the problem, that's the entire error message. `sshfs` doesn't have verbose mode.

Comment: Does not have? `-o sshfs_debug  print some debugging information`

Comment: @Jakuje oh, I totally missed that in the man page, I was only searching for 'verbose'. I'll try that!

Comment: I tried added the `sshfs_debug` option, but now all it does it print the version. It still gives me just the `Bad Address` error message with no further information.

Comment: Do you have something interesting in your ssh configuration or in `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 4):

You are **not** specifying the mounting address (where to mount on the host machine). Do it like this

```
sudo sshfs username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ ~/mnt/remotefs .
```

to mount it on the current directory. Note the `.` at the end to represent the fact that we want to mount on the current directory.

Comment: I don't know how this was an answer to the OP question, however it was the answer to my problem which brought me here.

Answer (score 0):

in case it helps someone else, I just made sure the local folder existed.
for some crazy reason, something like "/Users/usernamehere/MT-owner/backup" would not work.

changed to "~/mt-backup"  (making sure folder was created beforehand with mkdir -p ~/mt-backup)  and it worked.